# Some heavy to assign created instance of class

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my class:

```
public class ContainerData
{
    private List<Dictionary<Contour<Point> , int>> ratioContoursCollection = new List<Dictionary<Contour<Point>,int>>();

    public List<Dictionary<Contour<Point>, int>> ratioContoursCollcProperty 
    {
        get { return ratioContoursCollection; }
        set { ratioContoursCollection = value; } 
    }
}
```

I created the instance of a class:

```
ContainerData _CD = new ContainerData();
```

I need to fill the `_CD` with the `newTriangleRation` and contours in for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    double newTriangleRatio = someFunc();
    Contour<Point> contours = someFunc2();  
    // assignment have to be here!!!
}
```

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Each `newTriangleRatio` will be in a separate dictionary?

Comment: Yes,it will be in seperate dict

Comment: And why `double`, since your dictionary takes `int` as values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dictionary<Contour<Point>,int> myDict = new Dictionary<Contour<Point>,int>();
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 int newTriangleRatio = someFunc();
 Contour<Point> contours = someFunc2();
 myDict.Add(contours,newTriangleRatio);
}
_CD.RatioContoursCollcProperty.Add(myDict);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    double newTriangleRatio = someFunc();
    Contour<Point> contours = someFunc2();
    Dictionary<Contour<Point>, int> dict = new Dictionary<Contour<Point>, int>();
    dict.Add(contours, (int)newTriangleRatio);
    _CD.ratioContoursCollcProperty.Add(dict);
}
```

Although having 5 dictionaries with only one key each doesn't make much sense to me...